# How to list /dev/sda usb storages mounted with a combobox

Tags: list, qt, combobox, usb, udev

I'm looking for the way to show up usb storage path when they are plugged in, the path must be shown in a combobox (in a gui that I'm designing with qt creator (qt 5.9)). I have been searching how to do it but I have not found anything. What I want it's something like:

https://catenarios2.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/002.jpg

Could you please help me to carry on my project? I would be very grateful if you provide an example.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Maybe, launching appropriate Linux command, like `lsblk -o KNAME`, via QProcess (and parsing the result afterwards) if sufficient for you? Using libudev API or libsysfs is also an option, but requires more effort.

Comment: It could be an option to be considerate, I'll study the way to implement it into my program, thank you so much :). And how could I get the mountpint too? Finally it's what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is the same -- you launch Linux tool via `QProcess` and parse the result. Here is a simple sketch:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

#include <usb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess devList;
    devList.start("lsblk", QStringList() << "-o" << "KNAME");
    if (!devList.waitForStarted())
        return false;

    if (!devList.waitForFinished())
        return false;

    QString result = QString(devList.readAll());
    qDebug() << result;

    return a.exec();
}
```

You can use any other siutable command (quite easy to find them) and should improve parsing, of course, but generally it's all the same.

AFAIK, mount points could be obtained from `/proc/mounts` with something like...

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <mntent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    struct mntent *ent;
    FILE *aFile;

    aFile = setmntent("/proc/mounts", "r");
    if (aFile == NULL) {
      perror("setmntent");
      exit(1);
    }
    while (NULL != (ent = getmntent(aFile))) {
      printf("%s %s\n", ent->mnt_fsname, ent->mnt_dir);
    }
    endmntent(aFile);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Better than `cat` launching or someting else, also taken from some snippet and should be improved.
And, finally, in case you'll need USD device info, it could be something like...

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <usb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();
    for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
    {
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next)
        {
            printf("Trying device %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
            printf("\tID_VENDOR = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
            printf("\tID_PRODUCT = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idProduct);
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

This needs `sudo apt-get libusb-dev` + compiling with `-lusb`.

Not really much of Qt in the problem and more fundamental "coding" solutions possible, but hopefully that'll give you a push towards appropriate solution.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the great answer, i'll try to implement to my program tomorrow :D